# GeoServer WMS won't load with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I know there are numerous posts on the web about this but I cannot get my WMS layer in GeoServer to load in OpenLayers. OpenLayers adds the layer to the 'layer switcher' but it's nowhere to be seen. I'm not sure if it makes a difference (I don't see how it would) but my layer is being stored in a PostGIS database and I can view it fine in GeoServer's layer preview. The layer is in EPSG 4326, which I know is the OpenLayers default, and I'm adding it to an OSM basemap. This is my full URL as in the GeoServer layer preview URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/envision/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=envision:basecamp_property&styles=&bbox=115.753479003906,-32.2068328857422,116.16431427002,-31.9231204986572&width=512&height=353&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers
```

And this is my code for OpenLayers to access and add the layer:

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('Rezoning Scenario',
                          'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/envision/wms',
                          {'layers': 'envision:basecamp_property'},
                          {isBaseLayer: false}
                      );
    map.addLayer(wms);
```

Any ideas why it may not be working?

Thanks in Advance.

Ro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! In addition to reprojecting from 4325 to 900913 in GeoServer, I also had to declare the projection as 900913 in the layer properties, like so:

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('Rezoning Scenario',
                          'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/envision/wms',
                          {'layers': 'envision:basecamp_property'},
                          {isBaseLayer: false,
                           projection: 'EPSG:900913'} //This part was required!
                      );
    map.addLayer(wms);
```

For some reason, not many examples I've found have had to do this, but I did to make it work.

R

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the OSM layer is actually in projection `EPSG:900913` where as your WMS layer is in `EPSG:4326`.  As you are the admin of your WMS it would probably be easiest for you to do thetransform there, i.e. request the WMS in `EPSG:900913` from your geoserver.

have a look at these links for more info :

http://blog.sumbera.com/2010/02/17/overlay-wms-on-google-in-openlayers/

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/WMS-reprojection-td3912439.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. I looked into reprojecting in GeoServer. I went into the layer's properties and tried setting the 'declared' SRS to 900913 (I tried 3857 as well) and then selected 'reproject native to declared' (I tried the 'force declared' option as well) but I still don't get the map appearing. I've checked numerous forums with people having and solving the same issue, but nothing seems to be working. I tried declaring the SRS in the OpenLayers WMS object as well. Not sure what to try now...